# Parameter elem of the linking function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got the following directive:

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function () {
    return {link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if ($scope.contextForm.$dirty) {
                    return "Unsaved data detected.";
                }
            }
        }
    };
})
```

As you can see, the directive is not really well written as it directly references the form `contextForm`.

What I wanted to do is something a bit more generic (so I could also use it on other forms):

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function ($window) {
    return {link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            // Make sure code is only executed if directive is place on a form
            // Should I even do this here??
            if (elem[0].tagName == "FORM") {
                var form = elem[0];
                $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if (form.className.indexOf("ng-dirty") > -1) {
                    return "Unsaved data detected.";
                }
            }
        }
    };
})
```

You'll notice that the code is still pretty ugly since `form.hasClass("ng-dirty")` or `form.$dirty()` didn't work... I also think that accessing `elem[0]` is not correct...

I'd really appreciate some help!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AngularJS form doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform):

> If name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto
>   the current scope under this name.

So you can access that controller by using `$eval` on the `name` attribute:

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            var formCtrl = $scope.$eval(attrs.name);
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if (formCtrl.$dirty) {
                    return "Unsaved data detected.";
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rely on FormController ( http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController )

So what you can do:

1. Add "`require: '^ngForm'"` to request form controller as parameter to you linking function
2. Add another parameter to your linking function (kind of `formCtrl`)
3. use `formCtrl.$dirty`

If it is not clear for you, create plunker example with directive and I'll try to make these changes on it.